# .htaccess not redirecting web site to https

Tags: .htaccess, ssl, centos

I am running Apache/2.2.15 on Centos 6.6 and am using a free certificate from StartCom.  My home page file is /var/www/index.php so I create a file /var/www/.htaccess with the following content, as suggested [here](https://wiki.apache.org/httpd/RewriteHTTPToHTTPS).

```
RewriteEngine On
# This will enable the Rewrite capabilities

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !=on
# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS

RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{SERVER_NAME}/$1 [R,L]
# This rule will redirect users from their original location, to the same location but using HTTPS.
# i.e.  http://www.example.com/foo/ to https://www.example.com/foo/
# The leading slash is made optional so that this will work either in httpd.conf
# or .htaccess context
```

However, entering

```
myWebSite.com
```

in the URL box brings up my site in http protocol.  If I enter

```
https://myWebSite.com
```

instead, I get my site in https protocol.  My goal is to get my site in https protocol by simply entering

```
myWebSite.com
```

and I cannot see why the .htaccess file is not effecting that.

Comment: Are you sure your .htaccess is being read? Do you have `AllowOverride All` in your config?

Comment: That fixed the original problem.  Now, when I enter mywebsite.com, I get "The page isn't redirecting properly.  Firefox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete."  I was not getting that problem before.  Is there a problem with my .htaccess file?  Thanks,

Comment: Did you have this error before or after trying my answer?

Comment: It was after.  There appears to be a problem with RewriteRule ^/?(.*) https://%{HTTP_HOST}/$1 [R=301,L].  I don't get the problem if I comment is out but then I don't get any redirection, in that case, either.  Thanks,

Comment: did you try and clear your cache? Or try in another browser, Or change to 302 and that will remove the cache to see if the redirect works then you can change it back.

Comment: I changed to 302 and cleared my cache but the problem persisted.  I tried Chrome (instead of FireFox) on another browser and got "You don't have permission to access / on this server.  Additionally, a 403 Forbidden error was enocountered while trying to use an Error Document to handle the request."  Thanks,

Comment: That's a different error. Add `DirectoryIndex index.php` to the very top of the .htaccess file and try again in Chrome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It doesn't appear that your .htaccess file is being read. So make sure you have `AllowOverride All` in your config.

Also for your rules, I wouldn't use `SERVER_NAME`, that isn't always set and sometimes is not correct. I would either use `HTTP_HOST` variable or your actual domain name. You also should specificy `301` for your redirect because without it `302` is default. You want this to be a permanent redirect.

```
RewriteEngine On
# This will enable the Rewrite capabilities
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} !^on [OR]
# This checks to make sure the connection is not already HTTPS
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.example\.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^/?(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R=301,L]
```

I also made it where it would remove the `www` since you don't show your are using it.